# JAVA saber si un Puzzle n X n tiene Solucion

Tags: java, android, game

Quisiera saber cómo realizar un código que me permita saber si un puzle n xn (en el cual genero las posiciones al azar [ y dejo una foto del juego ]) tiene solución , por lo que vi no todas las diferentes posibilidades de generar un puzle tienen solución, encontré un código que supuestamente me decía si era solucionable o no, pero comparé resultados con un verificador en linea y no es 100% efectivo.

```
//Code
 public boolean isSolvable(List<Integer> puzzle, int squartRoot) {
        int parity = 0;
        int gridWidth = squartRoot;
        int row = 0;
        int blankRow = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.size(); i++) {
            if (i % gridWidth == 0) {
                row++;
            }
            if (puzzle.get(i) == 0) {
                blankRow = row;
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = i + 1; j < puzzle.size(); j++)
            {
                if (puzzle.get(i) > puzzle.get(j) && puzzle.get(j) != 0)
                {
                    parity++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (gridWidth % 2 == 0) {
            if (blankRow % 2 == 0) {
                return parity % 2 == 0;
            } else {
                return parity % 2 != 0;
            }
        } else {
            return parity % 2 == 0;
        }
    }
```

//Foto del juego

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que pueda servir tanto 3 x3 como 4 x4 etc u_u" no le logrado hace que funcione correctamente

Comment: Y... cuál es la solución del puzzle?

Comment: pues quedan todos en orden del 1 al n